# why Fetch Api don't post new state updated in useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using useReducer and context to update my state in App.js then sent data to the database but it doesn't Post a new updated state, and always send non-updated state.

**App.js**

```
import AuthContext from './context';
import screenA from './screenA';

export default function App() {

 const initialLoginState = {
   email: null,
 };
const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
     case 'Email':
       return {
         ...prevState,
         email: action.Email,
       };
   }
 };

const authContext = React.useMemo(
   () => ({
     email: emailUser => {
       dispatch({type: 'Email', Email: emailUser});
     },
     signIn: async () => {
       try {
         fetch('FakeApi', {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
             Accept: 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({
             email: loginState.email,
             date: '2021-9-20',
           }),
         });
       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
       }
     },
   }),
   [],
 );
 const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
   loginReducer,
   initialLoginState,
 );

return (
   <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
         <screenA />
   </AuthContext.Provider>
```

> Blockquote context

I create a separate context component

**context.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

> Blockquote screenA

In screenA I use email and signIn to send data to App.js and then save this data in the database

**screenA.js**

```
import {AuthContext} from './context';

function screenA() {
 const {email,signIn} = React.useContext(AuthContext);
 return (
   <View style={{marginTop: 150}}>
     {/* Count: {state.count} */}
     <Button
       title="sent email"
       onPress={() => {
         email('example@gmail.com');
       }}
     />
     <Button
       title="signIn"
       onPress={() => {
         signIn();
       }}
     />
   </View>
 );
}

export default screenA;
```

Comment: where you updating data. i dont see you setting state in exmaple.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the fetch response